# How calculate and chose the right BJT that comands a relay

Tags: relay, bjt

I was projecting a simple circuit that, from a digital OUTPUT from an Arduino zero (3.3 V) switch on a BJT that is connected to a relay.

The base of the BJT must have a current of about 5mA or less. Is this configuration enough to run a relay?

I have simulated this circuit and Ic is about 49mA; if I change the relay, Ic increases or it's fixed?

I'm not really good at this thing

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEMspa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

> if I change the relay, Ic increases or it's fixed?

Different relays will draw different coil currents at their designed operating voltage.
Check the datasheet for your relay.

50 mA is a reasonable number for a low power 5 V relay, but pretty low if your relay is rated for more than ~2 A switched current.

To maintain your 5 mA base current limit you might need to either use a Darlington configuration, or change from a BJT to a logic-level MOSFET.

Answer (score 0):

A BJT can be considered a "current amplifier", therefore its gain is of interest. In your case (5mA/50mA) this gain is relatively low

Answer (score 0):

A BJT can be considered a "current amplifier", therefore its gain is of interest. In your case (5mA/50mA) this gain is relatively low. For a given amplification, figure out the required base current. The base circuitry is then quite similar to a resistor-LED-circuit.

Note, that Ic is specific for the used relay (datasheet).

Comment: Please don't double post. You can edit your previous answer any time by clicking "edit" below the answer text.

Comment: Sorry, that was an accident...